# Next.JS getstaticprops revalidate not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, next.js

[image]

In index.js i used getStaticProps function and export it. I wanted to whenever a user visit my page, my api call will run. But i wanted to make this api call every (for example) 60 seconds, not everytime for every user. But, revalidate its not working. I deployed it on vercel. But my website is making api call just ONCE and not doing again.

How can i fix that issue?

Here is my webstie: emirhash.vercel.app

Comment: Which Next.js version are you using? revalidation is only available after Next.js 9.5

Comment: my next version is 12.1.5

Comment: did you use `getStaticPaths`?

Comment: No i didn't why should i use it? Is getStaticProps not enough for this? How should i implement it is there any docs for my goal?

Comment: My page is updated after a long while now im able to see my current database data correctly. Is next.js calling my api every 1 hour or something?

Comment: You set `60` which means 60 seconds. I'm not sure about whole your setup

Comment: If you guys can check out my website, you will its single page. Im getting my data with graphql. My data contains my projects name, url etc... Thats it. I want to fetch this data every 60 seconds. Do i need to getStaticPaths for that?

Comment: The document usually mentions `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` as a pair, so it's worth trying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244003/discussion-between-questiontoansw-and-nick-vu).

Answer (score 0):

Revalidation is working correctly but your ApolloClient is caching the graphql request, so that is why `getStaticProps` returns the same result everytime.

To fix this, set the `fetchPolicy` to `"network-only"` for that query.

```js
const { data } = await client.query({
  query: yourQuery,
  fetchPolicy: "network-only"
});
```